# Finding a null value in a collection and update

Tags: mongodb

write procedure for the below criteria.

I have some collections which contains object, array and nested arrays and not all are the same eg:

```
{
  FirstName: "Some",
  LastName: "Thing",
  Alias: null,
  Addresss: {
    Addressline1: "i234 some street",
    Addressline2: null,
    City: "City",
    Phone: {
      LandLine: 1234556778,
      Work: null,
      Mobile: 832923891,

    }
  }
}
```

How can I write a update procedure irrespective of a collection  to find all null values and update to "Missing"

Comment: `db.collection.update({Alias: null}, {Alias: "Missing"})`

Comment: @ExplosionPills That would replace the whole doc, not just the `Alias` field.

Comment: I think the OP wants to replace all fields which have null values with "Missing"

Comment: Thank you and Yes I want a query which can check all the objects and arrays  with a certain value to be updated to a desired value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below query and run it with multi: true option.

```
db.collection.update({Alias: null}, {$set: {Alias: "Missing"}}, {multi: true})
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#examples

Comment: I think the OP wants to replace all fields which have null values with "Missing", this only updates the `Alias` property.

Comment: @lalit Agarwal. Yes like Chridam mentioned I want to update addressline2, work as well. I want a query which can check all the objects and arrays  with a certain value to be updated to a desired value.

Comment: @Sravan : I am not aware of doing that in a single query, you might have to write a script and fire the update statement. Alternatively, you can fire this update statement for each of your key. Basically, you could replace "Alias" with "Addresses.Phone.work" and fire the same update statement.

Comment: @lalit Agarwal. True but i was having issues with nested arrays and I am kinda new and confused. Will give work on it, and thank you for the help.